# For an Xcode project, is it good to add .xcodeproj files to the source control as well?

Tags: xcode, git, svn, version-control

I am using Xcode 4.3.2 and realized that the project files are not added to the git repo, so I added them and committed:  (there are 6 files)

```
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   new file:   Proj01.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/contents.xcworkspacedata
#   new file:   Proj01.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/jeremy.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate
#   new file:   Proj01.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/jeremy.xcuserdatad/WorkspaceSettings.xcsettings
#   new file:   Proj01.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/jeremy.xcuserdatad/xcdebugger/Breakpoints.xcbkptlist
#   new file:   Proj01.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/jeremy.xcuserdatad/xcschemes/FlipCard.xcscheme
#   new file:   Proj01.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/jeremy.xcuserdatad/xcschemes/xcschememanagement.plist
```

but is it actually a good practice to do so?  (one time Xcode crashed and the folder .xcodeproj was gone).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As said your .xcodeproj is very important and should be included in your commit

I just want to add this link about using xcode with git which helped me a lot : http://shanesbrain.net/2008/7/9/using-xcode-with-git

Answer (score 5):

It's important to add the `project.pbxproj` file, but nothing else in the `.xcodeproj` bundle *needs* to be under version control.

Answer (score 2):

Well, since all the file references, build settings, target options are saved in the .xcodeproj file, yes, you should include it in your repository. I usually exclude most (if not all) user specific files, such as breakpoints, user interface state etc.